# Include fragments in themeleaf layout based on condition using Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am very newbie to Thymeleaf template engine, but i have working with other template engine like blade.

I want to include fragment based on condition like i have different menus for different users for example admin, manager, super user, user etc. I have keep these menus in headers and each header is in different fragment file like `adminheader, defaultheader, userheader.html`.

Now i want to check what whether user is logined or not. If not logined than display layout with defaultheader or if logined, than check user is admin or not. If user is admin than display page with adminheader otherwise display page page with userheader.

**Efforts:**

Till now page is opening with the default header and i have design layout file like below code,

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head layout:include="layouts/fragments/head :: headFragment">

  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="container-fluid">
           <header id="header" class="row navbar-fixed-top" layout:include="layouts/fragments/header :: headerFragment" >
           </header>
           <section class="row margin-top-120">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                    <section id="main-content" class="col-lg-12" layout:fragment="content">
                    </section>               
               </div>
           </section>
           <footer id="footer" class="row">
               <div class="container-fluid" layout:include = "layouts/fragments/footer :: footerFragment">

               </div>
           </footer>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I have included `headerFragment` in this layout file and working fine. Now don't know how to include other header fragment based on condition.

```
**Updated**
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(User user) {
        logger.info("Hello Get Login");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/validateLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        logger.info(user.toString());
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            logger.info(bindingResult.toString());
            return "login";
        }
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(){
        return "index";
    }

....
}
```

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expressions for the include of different fragments on a condition. There is an example in the [docs of thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html).

> In `templatename :: domselector`, both `templatename` and `domselector` can be fully-featured expressions. In the below example we want to include different fragments depending on a condition. If the authenticated user is an Admin, we will show a different footer than for a regular user:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: ${#authentication.principal.isAdmin()} ? 'footer-admin' : 'footer'">
  &copy; 2013 The Static Templates
</div>
```

Comment: please tell me whether my answer to my own question is correct or not. Or it will create issue in term of performance etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Patrick for your answer. But i have found the solution own.

I don't know whether it is good or not. Please tell.

layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head layout:include="layouts/fragments/head :: headFragment"></head>
  <body>
       <div class="container-fluid">
            ((${session.containsKey('user')}) ? 
            <header id="header" class="row navbar-fixed-top" layout:include="layouts/fragments/admin-Header :: headerFragment">
           </header> : 
           <header id="header" class="row navbar-fixed-top" layout:include="layouts/fragments/default-Header :: headerFragment">
           </header>)
           <section class="row margin-top-120">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                    <section id="main-content" class="col-lg-12" layout:fragment="content">
                    </section>               
               </div>
           </section>
           <footer id="footer" class="row">
               <div class="container-fluid" layout:include = "layouts/fragments/footer :: footerFragment">

               </div>
           </footer>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I think you are using java code directly in your html. Thats not the best solution for your use case. Just give an attribute from your controller to your view and use it the way like the docs say. If and else conditions are also able within a html attribute. `th:if`

Comment: Your answer is good but i have different file not section in file, as you mention in your answer. If your can modify your answer like my answer it will be good as i am not having section instead i am having file.

Comment: Updated. Kindly check.